# Installing and running emscripten on OSX 10.15

Tags: macos, webassembly, emscripten

I recently installed emscripten on my macbook air using homebrew.
But when I try to run it, even if i do a simple `emcc --version` i get the error `llc executable not found at /usr/bin/llc`. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

solution: llvm was not installed, so a `brew install llvm` followed by `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hrm. Seems like adding `brew install llvm`, I'm still not able to call `llvm` on my end.

So i just installed `brew install emscripten`
then I did `emcc` giving me

```
Welcome to Emscripten!

This is the first time any of the Emscripten tools has been run.

A settings file has been copied to /usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.39.18/libexec/.emscripten, at absolute path: /usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.39.18/libexec/.emscripten

It contains our best guesses for the important paths, which are:

  LLVM_ROOT       = /usr/bin
  NODE_JS         = /usr/local/bin/node
  EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT = /usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.39.18/libexec

Please edit the file if any of those are incorrect.

This command will now exit. When you are done editing those paths, re-run it.
```

Then i did `emcc` again, giving me `BINARYEN_ROOT is set to empty value in /usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.39.18/libexec/.emscripten`.

How did you set your BINARYEN_ROOT? i'm on the newest `macos  10.15.5`.

Comment: i added `export BINARYEN="/usr/local/opt/binaryen/bin"` to my `.zshrc` but then when i try to run `emcc` now i get a different set of errors, you can see them here and please help if you can https://pastebin.com/2H9dRczr